# ASP.NET: CSS friendly calendar control

Tags: asp.net, css, calendar

I'm using the built-in Calendar control. It works, but in a few places the way the HTML is rendered is broken or not CSS-friendly and unfortunately cannot be changed (it's hard coded). I was hoping they would fix this in .NET 4.0, but as far as I can tell the Calendar control hasn't been changed at all. Also, as far as I know, there's no CSS adapter for the Calendar control.

So, I would need a control that would:

- Allow me to customize the content of each cell (like OnDayRender works)
- Allow me to assign CSS classes to any HTML it may render
- Not render anything automatically that cannot be turned off, except layout code
- No auto-postback or auto-JS code (I can handle these by hand using simple links or custom JS calls)

Basically a simple calendar view control that would give me full rendering control.

What would you recommend?

Comment: using a jquery calendar is an option?

Comment: Just because there isn't an adapter for it doesn't mean you can't write your own (maybe a PITA, but possible).

Comment: @Claudio: Everything I found about jQuery calendar is showing it as a date picker. I would need the calendar to be always visible and add lots of custom code in each cell.

Comment: There are other calendars besides the datepicker. Take a look here http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins-for-web-designers/.  Are any of those helpful by any chance?

Comment: Come to think of it, it's not even that much of a pain to implement an adapter, here's the code for the Wizard adapter, it's only 100 lines of code http://code.google.com/p/aspnetcontroladapters/source/browse/trunk/src/ControlAdapters/Renderers/WizardHtmlRenderer.cs

Comment: @R0MANARMY: I've worked with a few jq calendars. Most are very client-side focused and heavily specialized for a given task, which is usually a good thing. In my case I'm basically looking for a "frame" I could build on.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: I will look more into how adapters work (never wrote one). If I could use it to just tweak the bits that need to be changed it would be perfect. Thanks.

Comment: you can use this http://www.west-wind.com/WestwindWebToolkit/samples/Ajax/jQueryDatePicker.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find what I was looking for, so I wrote one: http://basecalendar.codeplex.com/